# Getting an email notification when a new Drush version is available

Tags: drush

With standard Drupal modules, you get an email notification when there's an updated version.

How can we have this option with Drush?

I searched the official http://drush.org website and unfortunately there's no mailing list or RSS feed so that we know when there's a new version of Drush out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the [Drush project page](http://drupal.org/project/drush) on Drupal.org then you can follow the ["Releases" RSS feed](http://drupal.org/node/97249/release/feed) found at the bottom of the page.

**EDIT**

You can also use the [IFTTT.com](http://ifttt.com) service if you want the e-mails.  Just set up a rule on the site so that when the RSS feed gets updated, it sends you an e-mail.

Comment: PS! The current RSS feed (after the move to Github) seems to be https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.atom