# Get a notification if a new version (tag) is created

Tags: drush, updating, notifications

Before there was a RSS fead that got update if a new release of drush is available, see question:
[Getting an email notification when a new Drush version is available](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50653/getting-an-email-notification-when-a-new-drush-version-is-available).

But after drush is moved to github it seems that the RSS feed does not get updated anymore.

Is there a possibility to get an email notification if a new release tag is created on the github site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly through Github, but check https://sibbell.com

It's notifies you of new Github releases.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the standard release feed work for Drush?

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.atom

Anyway, this questions isn't really about Drush, but about Github and the feeds they provide. I suspect somebody will close this question ;-)

Added: Looking closely at the question, I see that what is requested is an email notification. Then probably the other answer is better. My bad.